# Story of a young child on earth who looked different, later exchanged for a human boy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

30-40 years ago I read a short story of a child with an abnormal feature (might have had just one eye?), loved by his parents and trying to live a normal life. I believe his name was Victor, and at the end he was exchanged for a boy from another place (planet?) who was "abnormal" there, but normal on Earth.  I remember it being a short story likely from a collection of short stories of similar sci-fi style.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of *[Eye of the Beholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Beholder_(The_Twilight_Zone%2C_1959))* but it doesn't really match past the "considered ugly there" aspect.

Comment: I think I read this story, or one with a similar theme, in middle school, back in the 1970s. The earth boy had a cone-shaped head with a spiral flap of skin and a tuft of hair at the peak. He volunteered for an exchange with a newly contacted alien planet because he felt too freakish on earth. The exchanged alien looked like a normal earthling, but when the protagonist left the exchange point and went out among the people on his new home, he found that all of them had cone-heads. The alien youth was a freak on his own world. I can't recall the story's name. From a magazine in English class.

Comment: Stanley, I was going to mention the cone shaped head but thought I might have been mixing it up with another story.  I don't recall the hair at the peak, but the rest of your description and the story line are what I remember.  If it's a magazine story it might be even harder to find the name, I don't know that I read it in school or at home, but late 1970s or early 1980s would be the timeframe.  Thank you!